# How to retreive stack from Database

Tags: database, sqlite

I have this table called 'Stack'.

```
+---------------+-------+-------------+
| Stack_Counter | value | Stack_Depth |
+---------------+-------+-------------+
|             1 |     3 |           1 |
|             2 |     0 |           2 |
|             3 |     0 |           1 |
|             4 |       |           0 |
|             5 |     3 |           1 |
|             6 |     3 |           2 |
|             7 |     1 |           3 |
|             8 |     2 |           2 |
|             9 |     4 |           1 |
|            10 |     2 |           2 |
|            11 |     0 |           3 |
|            12 |     0 |           2 |
|            13 |     0 |           1 |
|            14 |     2 |           2 |
|            15 |     2 |           3 |
|            16 |     1 |           4 |
|            17 |     1 |           3 |
|            18 |     2 |           2 |
|            19 |     1 |           3 |
|            20 |     0 |           4 |
+---------------+-------+-------------+
```

I want to find out the stack array in Stack_Counter '20'.

So the correct answer should be

```
+---------------+-------+-------------+
| Stack_Counter | value | Stack_Depth |
+---------------+-------+-------------+
|            13 |     0 |           1 |
|            18 |     2 |           2 |
|            19 |     1 |           3 |
|            20 |     0 |           4 |
+---------------+-------+-------------+
```

Basically , this is to find out consecutive rows in selected Stack_Depth.

Is there any way to acheive it?

Comment: One way is with [window functions](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html).  Sorry not a full answer right now, but it's a hint toward a working solution.  The underlying concept here is that each row is NOT independent, rather there is a complex relationship between rows.  Window functions allow processing of neighboring rows in particular groups (partitions) and sorts (orders).  *Without* the use of window functions, this is sometimes possible using convoluted series of subqueries, but it often requires processing data outside SQL using another language.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The window functions I mentioned in comments proved to be more difficult than I thought... for myself at the time.  Peak's answer is an elegant solution using the rank() window function, just what I had originally intended.  In the mean time, sqlite also supports [recursive CTE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) (Common Table Expressions; WITH statement):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
     latest (id, level) AS (
          VALUES (20, (SELECT Stack_Depth FROM stack WHERE Stack_Counter = 20))
          UNION ALL
          SELECT (SELECT max(Stack_Counter) 
                  FROM stack
                  WHERE Stack_Depth = level - 1
                        AND Stack_Counter <= 20),
                  level - 1
          FROM latest
          WHERE level - 1 > 0
     )
SELECT stack.*
FROM stack INNER JOIN latest
     ON stack.Stack_Counter = latest.id
ORDER BY stack.Stack_Counter
```

There are three places that I had to insert the desired stack level, but these could all be replaced with a named SQL parameter if you're calling this from a prepared statement in the host language.

And if you're not interested in choosing a particular Stack_Counter value, rather just want the result from the entire table, then replace the `VALUES` clause with a SELECT like

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
     latest (id, level) AS (
          SELECT * FROM (SELECT Stack_Counter, Stack_Depth FROM stack ORDER BY Stack_Counter DESC LIMIT 1)
          UNION ALL
          SELECT (SELECT max(Stack_Counter) 
                  FROM stack
                  WHERE Stack_Depth = level - 1),
                  level - 1
          FROM latest
          WHERE level - 1 > 0
     )
SELECT stack.*
FROM stack INNER JOIN latest
     ON stack.Stack_Counter = latest.id
ORDER BY stack.Stack_Counter
```

Answer (score 1):

... and here's a generic all-SQL solution:

```
SELECT Stack_Counter, value, Stack_Depth 
FROM
  (SELECT *, RANK() OVER (
      PARTITION BY Stack_Depth
      ORDER BY Stack_Counter DESC) rank
   FROM stack)
WHERE rank=1 AND Stack_Depth > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

An SQL-only solution may be more trouble than it's worth (either because of its complexity or its tediousness), but here is one that works with SQLite:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM stack WHERE Stack_Depth=1 ORDER BY Stack_Counter DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM stack WHERE Stack_Depth=2 ORDER BY Stack_Counter DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM stack WHERE Stack_Depth=3 ORDER BY Stack_Counter DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM stack WHERE Stack_Depth=4 ORDER BY Stack_Counter DESC LIMIT 1);
```